# ¿Existen palabras con construcción similar a "penúltimo"?

Tags: etimología, prefijos

La definición en el DLE para penúltimo es:

> [**penúltimo, ma**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SUeW37n)
>
> Del lat. *paenultĭmus*.
>
> 1. *adj*. Inmediatamente anterior al último o a lo último.

En [wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pen%C3%BAltimo)  se explica un poco más su etimología:

> Del latín *paenultimus* y éste a su vez de *paene*, "casi" y *ultimus*, "último"

Entonces, penúltimo vendría siendo como el "casi último". ¿Existen otras palabras en español que usen la partícula originada de *paene* con el significado de "casi"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sí, por ejemplo `península`

> [península](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SSzcHpj)
>
> Del lat. paeninsŭla.
>
> 1. f. Tierra cercada por el agua, y que solo por una parte relativamente estrecha está unida y tiene comunicación con otra tierra de extensión mayor.

Que como podemos apreciar en la [etimología](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?peni.nsula) es un compuesto de *paene* (casi) e *insula* (isla). Es decir, que **una península es casi una isla**.

El mismo enlace aporta también `penumbra` (**casi sombra** o casi oscuridad)

> [penumbra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SUgZozU)
>
> Del lat. paene 'casi' y umbra 'sombra'.
>
> 1. f. Sombra débil entre la luz y la oscuridad, que no deja percibir dónde empieza la una o acaba la otra.

Comment: ¡Ahora nunca voy a olvidar que significa península!

Comment: Yo, fedorqui, hijo de fedor, te hago entrega de una recompensa de 100 puntos en nombre de toda la comunidad y como agradecimiento por tu espléndida respuesta, que quedó clasificada en segunda plaza (_ex aequo_) en el primer concurso [Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2017 Q4)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2787/1674).

Answer (score 5):

Por dar un par de palabras más con una etimología un poco más rebuscada:

> **[penitencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ST3BLoU)**
>
> Del lat. *paenitentia*.
>
> 1. f. Dolor y arrepentimiento que se tiene de una mala acción, o sentimiento de haber ejecutado algo que no se quisiera haber hecho.
> 2. ...

Asegura la web del *Diccionario etimológico del español* [lo siguiente](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?penitencia):

> La palabra **penitencia** viene del latín *paenitentia* (arrepentimiento, dolor, disgusto), nombre formado con el sufijo compuesto *-entia* (cualidad de un agente), sobre la raíz de un verbo impersonal *paenitere* (arrepentirse). Pero este verbo en origen significó "no tener bastante de algo, no estar contento o satisfecho" y parece que se deriva del adverbio *paene* (casi, poco más o menos, con falta), adverbio que encontramos en palabras como *península* (casi una isla) o *penúltimo* (casi el último).

Y la segunda:

> **[penuria](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SUn5tzT)**
>
> Del lat. *penuria*.
>
> 1. f. Escasez, falta de las cosas más precisas o de alguna de ellas.

De la cual asegura la misma web citada anteriormente [lo siguiente](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?penuria):

> [...] En este sentido Ernout y A. Meillet (*Dictionaire Étymologique de la Langue Latine*) apuntan a una derivación a partir de *paene* (casi). La formación es explicable porque los adverbios muestran en composición antigua con mucha frecuencia una variante sigmática (que pudo ser *paenes*) y los radicales muestran una alternancia frecuente en -es/-us o us-/es- (como en *tempus-/tempes-*), de manera que la palabra arcaica sería **paenusia*, luego alterada la *s* por el rotacismo.

Answer (score 3):

Agrego éstas:

> **[penillanura](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SSoVA3w)**
>
> **1**. f. *Geogr.* Terreno casi llano, con leves ondulaciones, cuya formación y características son resultado de la erosión de una zona
>   montañosa.
>
> **[penisla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ST2iso3)**
>
> **1**. f. península.

Probablemente (no lo sé) también la cordillera **Penibética** y sus gentilicios, y la palabra **pendencia** que (según una versión) vendría de *penitencia*, ya mencionada por Charly.

Answer (score 1):

Además de los que comienzan *pen-*, hay:

- *apenas* < *ad paene*
- *antepenúltimo* < *ante paenultimus* <  *ante + paene + ultimus*